# UI fields not getting aligned centre-horizontally

Tags: html, css

I've a piece of sample UI code which looks as under :

```
<form class="form form-horizontal">
     <div style="display: inline">
         <control-group v-field="student.status" width="6">
             <div style="display: inline">
                 <span class="student-marks" id="studentMarks">{{studentMarks}}</span>
             </div>
         </control-group>
     </div>
</form>
```

Basically I wanted the "student.status" and "studentMarks" to be displayed in a "center-horizontal-aligned" fashion.

But that didn't work for me with the "display: inline" attribute.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly a little unsure on what you're looking for, but it sounds like you simply want
`text-align: center` on `form`.

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="form form-horizontal">
  <div style="display: inline">
    <control-group v-field="student.status" width="6">
      <div style="display: inline">
        <span class="student-marks" id="studentMarks">{{studentMarks}}</span>
      </div>
    </control-group>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that `text-align: center` and `display: inline` won't work together when applied to the same element, but if you're willing to remove `display: inline`, you could apply `text-align: center` to the `<div>` element itself.

Comment: The issue is that "student.status" (which is a label) and {{studentMarks}} appear next to each other but {{studentMarks}} appears slightly above "student.status". I want their centers to be horizontally aligned, they shouldn't appear like " - _" but more like " - - ".

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tbl{
    display: table;  
    width: 100%;
}

.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 180px;
    background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form class="form form-horizontal">
     <div style="display: inline">
         <control-group v-field="student.status"   class="tbl">
             <div class="cell">
                 <span class="student-marks" id="studentMarks">{{studentMarks}}</span>
             </div>
         </control-group>
     </div>
</form>
```